# recalculate table height on window resize 

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this function that does 3 things :

- tr hover
- focus on two separate tables displayed on the same line
- calculate tr height from first table and set that height to tr from second table.

---

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var rows = $('.interactive tr');
    rows.click(function () {
        var i = $(this).GetIndex() + 1; // nth-child is 1-based
        rows.removeClass('selectedRow');
        rows.filter(':nth-child(' + i + ')').addClass('selectedRow');
    });

    rows.hover(function(){
        var i = $(this).GetIndex() + 1;
        rows.filter(':nth-child(' + i + ')').addClass('hoverx');
    },function(){         
        rows.removeClass('hoverx');
    });

    $("table:first tr").each(function(i) {
        $("table:last tr").eq(i).height($(this).height());
    });
});

jQuery.fn.GetIndex = function(){
    return $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
}
</script>
```

This function works great but I have a problem **when browser is resized** because the function is not recalculating tr height.

This ruins all the table design.

Can anyone help me with this please : how to recalculate tr height from first table and set to tr from second table when browser is resized.

Here is the `fiddle example:` http://jsfiddle.net/Ksb2W/59/

Thank you.

Comment: you have to use `$(window).resize(function(){ ... });` function, which is executed during resize of browser window.

Comment: already tried that but is not working, I think must be added a new condition,but I can think of nothing.

Comment: So, based on what you describe, I get the feeling that you want to have the two tables look as if they are the same table, correct? (i.e. the rows line up nicely)

Comment: in this fiddle none of the tr height changes when resize

Answer (score 2):

you need to put the height calculation in a resize function, also keep the one you have as is so it does it's job onload or move to before the resize function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
        // get first table tr height
        // apply to second table tr height
    });
});
```

you can see the resize being called here
http://jsfiddle.net/Ksb2W/103/

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but it's a couple of things to check that may get you where you're going.

- temporarily put in a button or something that will call your resizing function.  Then resize the window, then call the function.  This will tell you if your problem is in triggering the function with `$(window).resize` or in your function itself.
- If the problem is in the function itself, it may be that some of your problem is in browser caching.  Try calling .hide() and then .show() on the lot of it.